# Tidal Forces from the Moon on the Earth's Crust

Tags: geophysics, tidal-effect

How do we determine how much the surface of the Earth deflects due to [tidal forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_forces) from the Moon (and Sun)?

Comment: a good place to start: is [here](https://ca.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110209133756AANbKM1)

Comment: Are you asking how much the surface moves, or how we measure how much it moves?

Comment: I've read that it moves about 1/100 of how much tide water moves.  I have no idea if that is correct, so I guess I am asking both.

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia article on [Earth tides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_tide) includes a table showing how much the crust moves in response to the tidal forces from the Moon. The maximum movement is a shade under 40cm, though more typical would be 10 - 20cm. Ocean tides [can be up to 10m](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_range), though 4m would be a more reasonable value, so the movement of the crust is about one tenth that of the sea rather than one hundredth.

I'm afraid I don't know how such small movements in the crust are measured. I assume some form of surveying is used.

Comment: At the CERN accelerators they had to take into account the tides in corrections in space for the beams that travel the 30km tunnel. http://cds.cern.ch/record/250463/files/CM-P00061237.pdf . this is interesting http://www.slac.stanford.edu/econf/C0802113/papers/001.pdf